# Getting the http post canceled when subscribing from a service

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

Stuck in this error for a week. Cannot send a simple post request to the Heroku server using the Angular HttClient. Defined all the services in the provider section in the main app module. The Error Handling service is not logging any error after sending the post request(This service works fine that I have tested in another project).

The component is defined in a different module but services are defined and provided in the root app.module.ts

These modules that components live are imported in the main app module.

But no matter what the **post request being cancelled**!.

**API Params**

```
 email: string 
 password: string
```

**AuthModel**

Model using for defining the data params for API

```
export interface AuthModel {
    email: string;
    password: string
}
```

**AuthService.ts**

This is the service i used to inject into my component.ts file for subscribing. This service also uses another service to handle the error cases HandleError

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  signUpUrl = 'myurl';
  
  private handleError: HandleError;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private httpErrorService: HttpErrorService) { 

    this.handleError = this.httpErrorService.createHandleError('AuthService'); //Problem lies here
  }

  signUp(authModel:  AuthModel) : Observable<AuthModel>
  { 
    return this.http.post<AuthModel>(this.signUpUrl,authModel,httpOptions).pipe( catchError(this.handleError('signup',authModel)) );
  }

}
```

**component.ts**

Submit function is called when button is clicked after entering the data

```
Submit(): void {
    
    this.authModel!.email = this.emailHolder.value;
    this.authModel!.password = this.passwordHolder.value;

    this.authService.signUp(this.authModel).subscribe((res)=> {console.log(res)});
    
  }
```

[image: XHR is being while subscribing the observable service]

[image: Header Information]

[image: Payload Information]

Comment: Did you add `httpClientModule` inside app.module.ts or not ?

Comment: The preflight request has an unknown status, is that one getting cancelled as well? What is the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header? And also `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` ?

Comment: From Where you are calling submit() method ?

Comment: It seems you have `switchMap` on signup operation.

Comment: @GRD I did add httpClientModule inside the app.module.ts

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu That two properties are not showing in the console section
Only these two
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST

Comment: @GRD submit() is called in a different module inside the component mentioned in the question. It's a material button

Comment: These look like request headers, you should be searching the response headers for the ones that I mentioned. Maybe on the preflight request

Comment: @TonyMarko Can you explain a little bit about that? How do i resolve?

Comment: use mergeMap() instead of switchMap() @PatrickPrakash

Comment: @I haven't used any Mapping function just pipe

Comment: `this.handleError('signup',authModel)` what type is return by this function . it have to be observable . @PatrickPrakash and did you use any http-interceptor ?

Comment: @GRD The function handleError return as a observable of the result. I haven't used any http-interceptor

Comment: I tried logging the response to see why it is cancelled in preflight mode.
it says "preflight_required_reason":"disallowed_header"

Comment: But this same header was used to run this api on a different sample project

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my **handleError** function, it get's canceled not matter the response was. So make sure guys to write a proper errorHandling function, else you will get unintended result.